# stores 25 even integers into an integer array named intList then displays the array on the screen AND a data file called evenIntegers.txt

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

Here's my problem: 
Write a program that generates integers between 1 and 100 and stores 25 even integers into an integer array named intList then displays the array on the screen AND a data file called evenIntegers.txt.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    ofstream fout;
    int intList[25];
    fout.open("C:\\classdata\\evenintegers.txt");

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){

        if(i % 2 == 0) {

        cout << i <<" ";
        fout << i <<" ";
      }
   }

   fout.close();
   return 0;
   }
```

I am getting all the even numbers from 1- 100, but how do I stick 25 in the array AND displays the array on the screen AND a data file called evenIntegers.txt. I am sick so it's hard for me to concentrate on solving this.

Comment: If you can choose the 25 even integers, what about `if ( i % 4 == 0)`? Next you can write `intList[i/4] = i; fout << i << ' ';`

Comment: To avoid divisions, you can use bit-or and bit-shift; so `if ( (i & 3) == 0 )` and `intList[i>>2] = i;`

Comment: Off Topic: you tagged C++11, so you can use `std::array<int, 25U> intList;` instead of `int intList[25]`; I strongly suggest to use `std::array` instead of olds C-style arrays.

Comment: The compiler shutdown when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: The **compiler** shutdown?!? D'oh! Ok: I'll prepare my suggestions as an answer with a full example.

Comment: Well... I was wrong: not `intList[i/4] = i;` (or `intList[i>>2] = i;`) but `intList[(i/4)-1] = i` (or `intList[(i>>2)-1] = i`). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Following a couple of comment suggestions, I propose the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
 {
   std::ofstream fout;

   int intList[25];

   fout.open("foo.txt");

   for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; ++i)
    {
      if ( (i & 3) == 0 )
         intList[(i>>2) - 1] = i;
    }


   for ( unsigned int i = 0U ; i < sizeof(intList)/sizeof(intList[0]) ; ++i )
    {
      std::cout << intList[i] << ' ';
      fout << intList[i] << ' ';
    }

   std::cout << std::endl;
   fout << std::endl;

   fout.close();

   return 0;
 }
```

Observe that

- I've chose the multiples of 4, so you have 25 even number between 1 and 100;
- I've used the bit or `(i & 3) == 0` to see if a number can be divided (without rest) by 4
- I've used the bit-shift `i>>2` to divide the number by 4
- I've used the first loop just to prepare the values in the array and added a second loop (<s>a range-based for loop</s> (not a range-based for loop in C++98)) to print the values to screen and in the file.

Comment: I was wrong to put C++11. I am just learning basic C++ so I don't know what auto & std:: is. Also, I put your code into my complier, got the following error: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]|. Can you show me the basic way to do it?

Comment: @HTownGirl17 - It's a pity you can't use C++11: it brings a lot of improvement to the language. For example: my suggestion about `std::array` decay because `std::array` is introduced in C++11. Anyway, I've modified my answer to work with C++98: the first `auto` simply become `int`; but the second loop is completely rewritten because the first version was based on range-based for loop, another C++11 improvement.

Comment: He may very well be able to use C++11, if only someone would let him in on the compiler option `--std=c++11` (or with gnu extensions `--std=gnu++11`). Who knows, it just might work `:)` (or at least remove the `-Wc++0x-compat` his compiler is telling him about)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without changing your original code too much would be to add a **COUNTER** which increments whenever you output and insert to the file then stops when the desired count is reached

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    int counter = 0; // add this
    fout.open("C:\\classdata\\evenintegers.txt");

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            cout << i <<" ";
            fout << i <<" ";
            counter++; // increment every time the condition is met
        }
        if(counter >= 25)
            break; // stop when the desired count was reached
    }
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: *I want to keep your original code as much as possible and not bombard you with too much unexplored methods. There are a lot of ways to improve your solution but that will depend on your own knowledge.*